# Merging value of a column from a PHP table

Tags: php, html

I have a table and i want to merge the value of Total column for each month.

This is my code :

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" class="table_content">
   <tr>
      <td width="38" rowspan="2">NO.</td>
      <td rowspan="2">PILOT ON BOARD</td>
      <td colspan="2">PILOT ON BOARD</td>
      <td rowspan="2">PILOT WAITING TIME</td>
      <td rowspan="2">TOTAL</td>
      <td rowspan="2">BERTHING</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width="100">DATE </td>
      <td width="100">TIME</td>
   </tr>

   <?php
        $no=0;
        $dataFromTable=json_decode('[{"PilotWaitingTime":"0.2","PilotOnBoardDate":"2013-01-01","PilotOnBoardTime":"17:40:00","PilotOnBoard":"2013-01-01 17:40:00","Berthing":"2013-01-01 20:25:00","rata2PilotWaitingTime":"9.067"},{"PilotWaitingTime":"19.2","PilotOnBoardDate":"2013-01-03","PilotOnBoardTime":"12:15:00","PilotOnBoard":"2013-01-03 12:15:00","Berthing":"2013-01-03 15:10:00","rata2PilotWaitingTime":"9.067"},{"PilotWaitingTime":"7.8","PilotOnBoardDate":"2013-01-03","PilotOnBoardTime":"14:45:00","PilotOnBoard":"2013-01-03 14:45:00","Berthing":"2013-01-03 17:05:00","rata2PilotWaitingTime":"9.067"},{"PilotWaitingTime":"6.4","PilotOnBoardDate":"2013-02-04","PilotOnBoardTime":"18:25:00","PilotOnBoard":"2013-02-04 18:25:00","Berthing":"2013-02-04 20:25:00","rata2PilotWaitingTime":"6.000"},{"PilotWaitingTime":"5.6","PilotOnBoardDate":"2013-02-06","PilotOnBoardTime":"05:40:00","PilotOnBoard":"2013-02-06 05:40:00","Berthing":"2013-02-06 08:30:00","rata2PilotWaitingTime":"6.000"},{"PilotWaitingTime":"26","PilotOnBoardDate":"2013-03-04","PilotOnBoardTime":"13:00:00","PilotOnBoard":"2013-03-04 13:00:00","Berthing":"2013-02-04 20:25:00","rata2PilotWaitingTime":"26.000"}]',true);

        foreach( $dataFromTable as $results ){
   ?>

   <tr>
      <td width="38" style="text-align:right"><?php echo $no+=1; ?></td>
      <td width="150"><?php echo $results['PilotOnBoard']; ?></td>
      <td width="100"><?php echo $results['PilotOnBoardDate']; ?> </td>
      <td width="100"><?php echo $results['PilotOnBoardTime']; ?></td>
      <td style="text-align:right"><?php echo $results['PilotWaitingTime']; ?></td>
      <td style="text-align:right"><?php echo $results['rata2PilotWaitingTime']; ?></td>
      <td style="text-align:right"><?php echo $results['Berthing']; ?></td>
   </tr>

   <?php }; ?>

</table>
```

This is the result:

```
PilotOnBoard            PilotOnBoardDate PilotOnBoardTime   PilotWaitingTime    Total   Berthing
2013-01-01 17:40:00     2013-01-01       17:40:00                        0.2     9.067  2013-01-01 20:25:00
2013-01-03 12:15:00     2013-01-03       12:15:00                       19.2     9.067  2013-01-03 15:10:00
2013-01-03 14:45:00     2013-01-03       14:45:00                        7.8     9.067  2013-01-03 17:05:00
2013-02-04 18:25:00     2013-02-04       18:25:00                        6.4     6.000  2013-02-04 20:25:00
2013-02-06 05:40:00     2013-02-06       05:40:00                        5.6     6.000  2013-02-06 08:30:00
2013-03-04 13:00:00     2013-03-04       13:00:00                       26      26.000  2013-02-04 20:25:00
```

I'm trying to merge the total column for each month. January = 9.067, February 6.000 and March 26.000.

This is the result i'm trying to make:

```
PilotOnBoard            PilotOnBoardDate PilotOnBoardTime   PilotWaitingTime   Total    Berthing
2013-01-01 17:40:00     2013-01-01       17:40:00                        0.2   |      | 2013-01-01 20:25:00
2013-01-03 12:15:00     2013-01-03       12:15:00                       19.2   | 9.067| 2013-01-03 15:10:00
2013-01-03 14:45:00     2013-01-03       14:45:00                        7.8   |______| 2013-01-03 17:05:00
2013-02-04 18:25:00     2013-02-04       18:25:00                        6.4   | 6.000| 2013-02-04 20:25:00
2013-02-06 05:40:00     2013-02-06       05:40:00                        5.6   |______| 2013-02-06 08:30:00
2013-03-04 13:00:00     2013-03-04       13:00:00                       26     |26.000|     2013-02-04 20:25:00
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: You need it based on month? You do a averaging on the data??

Answer (score 0):

Check if it's the same month and add `rowspan` attribute to the td!

```
   <table border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" class="table_content">
   <tr>
      <td width="38" rowspan="2">NO.</td>
      <td rowspan="2">PILOT ON BOARD</td>
      <td colspan="2">PILOT ON BOARD</td>
      <td rowspan="2">PILOT WAITING TIME</td>
      <td rowspan="2">TOTAL</td>
      <td rowspan="2">BERTHING</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width="100">DATE </td>
      <td width="100">TIME</td>
   </tr>

   <?php
        $no=0;
        $rows = 1;
        $lastDate = null;
        $dataFromTable=json_decode('[{"PilotWaitingTime":"0.2","PilotOnBoardDate":"2013-01-01","PilotOnBoardTime":"17:40:00","PilotOnBoard":"2013-01-01 17:40:00","Berthing":"2013-01-01 20:25:00","rata2PilotWaitingTime":"9.067"},{"PilotWaitingTime":"19.2","PilotOnBoardDate":"2013-01-03","PilotOnBoardTime":"12:15:00","PilotOnBoard":"2013-01-03 12:15:00","Berthing":"2013-01-03 15:10:00","rata2PilotWaitingTime":"9.067"},{"PilotWaitingTime":"7.8","PilotOnBoardDate":"2013-01-03","PilotOnBoardTime":"14:45:00","PilotOnBoard":"2013-01-03 14:45:00","Berthing":"2013-01-03 17:05:00","rata2PilotWaitingTime":"9.067"},{"PilotWaitingTime":"6.4","PilotOnBoardDate":"2013-02-04","PilotOnBoardTime":"18:25:00","PilotOnBoard":"2013-02-04 18:25:00","Berthing":"2013-02-04 20:25:00","rata2PilotWaitingTime":"6.000"},{"PilotWaitingTime":"5.6","PilotOnBoardDate":"2013-02-06","PilotOnBoardTime":"05:40:00","PilotOnBoard":"2013-02-06 05:40:00","Berthing":"2013-02-06 08:30:00","rata2PilotWaitingTime":"6.000"},{"PilotWaitingTime":"26","PilotOnBoardDate":"2013-03-04","PilotOnBoardTime":"13:00:00","PilotOnBoard":"2013-03-04 13:00:00","Berthing":"2013-02-04 20:25:00","rata2PilotWaitingTime":"26.000"}]',true);

        foreach( $dataFromTable as $results ){
   ?>

   <tr>
      <td width="38" style="text-align:right"><?php echo $no+=1; ?></td>
      <td width="150"><?php echo $results['PilotOnBoard']; ?></td>
      <td width="100"><?php echo $results['PilotOnBoardDate']; ?> </td>
      <td width="100"><?php echo $results['PilotOnBoardTime']; ?></td>
      <td style="text-align:right"><?php echo $results['PilotWaitingTime']; ?></td>

      <?php 
      if(explode("-",$results['PilotOnBoardDate'])[1] !== $lastDate){?>
        <td style="text-align:right" rowspan="<?php echo $rows;?>"><?php echo $results['rata2PilotWaitingTime']; ?></td>
      <?php 
      } else {
        $rows++;
      }
      $lastDate = explode("-",$results['PilotOnBoardDate'])[1];
      ?>
      <td style="text-align:right"><?php echo $results['Berthing']; ?></td>
   </tr>

   <?php }; ?>

</table>
```

I think this should work!